# how to use smarty in WHMCS addon

Tags: php, whmcs

I am trying to develop a addon for my WHMCS using the WHMCS API and smarty.

I have created the module and now on load I create the new $smarty instance and then try to load the template file that is in the `addon_name/template` directory but i am unable.

Below is my code and my errors:

**WHMCS Output:**

```
function statement_generator_output($vars) {
      include('mainform.php');
}
```

**Mainform.php:**

```
<?

require_once '/home/account/public_html/hosting/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';

$smarty = new Smarty;

//$smarty->force_compile = true;
$smarty->debugging = true;
$smarty->caching = false;
$smarty->cache_lifetime = 120;

$smarty->assign("action", 'hello');

$smarty->display('/home/account/hosting/modules/addons/statement_generator/template/statement_generator.tpl');

?>
```

**Error:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template file '/home/account/hosting/modules/addons/statement_generator/template/statement_generator.tpl' <-- thrown in /home/account/public_html/hosting/includes/classes/WHMCS/Terminus.php on line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your path to template correct? 
I think you are missing **public_html** in template path

Answer (score 0):

just use the **FILE** magic constant.

```
$smarty = new Smarty();
        $smarty->assign('params1', $params);
        $smarty->caching = false;
        $smarty->compile_dir = $GLOBALS['templates_compiledir'];
        $smarty->display(dirname(__FILE__) . '/template/statement_generator.tpl');
```